# WHERE ,AND .OR in one request

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT * FROM company_disposition WHERE company_id = $1 AND campaign_uuid = 'null' OR campaign_uuid != $2
```

Here is my postgres request .. I wan't to get all values `which company_id = $1 AND campaign_uuid = 'null' OR campaign_uuid != $2` ..How to make it ? my request which u see isn't working //

```
 {
      "company_id": "be1b5ee1-51e7-422b-b469-592dbd62bec9",
      "disposition": "string",
      "disposition_uuid": "8f66c72a-9a68-440a-bd7f-3a0f49ef4973",
      "disposition_order": 2323,
      "campaign_uuid": "fd80a1fa-947d-4b09-a755-cee5951b6c85"
    },
    {
      "company_id": "be1b5ee1-51e7-422b-b469-592dbd62bec9",
      "disposition": "strinsdsdg",
      "disposition_uuid": "4c8e9601-1894-4e69-b22c-f2b83d9d80bb",
      "disposition_order": 2323,
      "campaign_uuid": null
    }
```

I want to get this one :

```
 {
      "company_id": "be1b5ee1-51e7-422b-b469-592dbd62bec9",
      "disposition": "strinsdsdg",
      "disposition_uuid": "4c8e9601-1894-4e69-b22c-f2b83d9d80bb",
      "disposition_order": 2323,
      "campaign_uuid": null
    }
```

`"campaign_uuid"` - can be as value or null

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your query (if I read it correctly):

1. You compare with NULL using the `=` operator.

   SQL uses *three-values logic* for the comparison operators, so that comparing NULL (= unknown) to anything is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`, but NULL.

   That implies that the condition `something = NULL` is never `TRUE` (it is always NULL).

   You have to use the `IS NULL` operator to test if a value is NULL.
2. You forget that `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, so you have to use parentheses.

I think you mean the following:

```
SELECT * FROM company_disposition
WHERE company_id = $1
  AND (campaign_uuid IS NULL OR campaign_uuid <> $2);
```

If you never supply a NULL value for $2, a simpler way would be

```
SELECT * FROM company_disposition
WHERE company_id = $1
  AND campaign_uuid IS DISTINCT FROM $2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM company_disposition WHERE company_id = $1 AND campaign_uuid is null OR campaign_uuid <> $2 AND company_id = $1
```

Comment: This lacks an explanation. it is technically correct, but won't help the OP see what was his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT * FROM company_disposition WHERE company_id = $1 AND (campaign_uuid is null OR campaign_uuid <> $2)
```

This query could return several rows, all rows with company_id = $ 1 and campaign_uuid != $ 2, (the condition campaign_uuid != $2 will include the rows with campaign_uuid = null), if you want to get only one row for each company_id, you need to use "DISTINCT"

Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (company_id)
     company_id,
     disposition,
     disposition_uuid,
     disposition_order,
     campaign_uuid
FROM
   company_disposition
WHERE
   company_id = $1 AND
   (campaign_uuid is null OR campaign_uuid <> $2)
ORDER BY company_id
```